# How to do animations in tableau? Create a dynamic bar charts

Tags: animation, tableau-api

Is it possible to create animations in tableau?

I have a bar chart and I want to enable the user to scroll the bar charts and display the values. I'm trying to let the user forecast. Is there any way to do this?

Thank you

Comment: Could you give a bit more detail what you want to do? It sounds like a couple of things at once: 1. Display values in Bar charts 2. Forecast data 3. Animate something.
There are ways to do all 3 of them (at least to a certain degree) but it really depends on your use-case

Comment: Sorry for being vague. So I have bar charts and I want to enable the user to increase or decrease the bars. There are 3 bars and the user should be able to drag the first two bars and the difference should be reflected in the third bar. If it's not possible to drag the bars, I'd like to provide a slider which changes the bar sizes and their corresponding values, so that the difference between the first two is shown in the third one.

Answer (score 0):

for animation (only work in tableau desktop app) you can use pages filter to display data one by one in animation
[image]